# "I am?" or "Me?", what is the difference between those responses

Tags: word-usage, questions

For example:

> "You have been promoted!"
>
> "Me?" or "I am?"

Comment: I would answer "You are promoted!" with "I am?", but "You have been promoted!" with "I was?"

Comment: Why not 'Am I'? or 'Was I'? @J.R.

Comment: 'You have been promoted' can be replied with 'Am I?' I think because the effect of being promoted still remains.

Comment: @MaulikV - Is the promotion a past event, or an ongoing one? As RuchirM says, when worded as "You have been promoted," it can be interpreted either way – but I think I'm more inclined to interpret the surprise announcement as a done deal, so I'd respond in the past. Similarly, if the person told me, "You're going to be promoted [at the end of next month]," I might answer, "I will?" (although "I am?" could work there, too; as in: "I am [going to be promoted next month]?").

Comment: There's also the response: *"I have?"*

Comment: @F.E. IMO, "I have?" is the most natural response ("I was?" would be an answer to "You were promoted!", it stays parallel).

Answer (score 2):

*Me?* means you are surprised that *you* are the one that has been promoted (you were expecting someone else to be promoted.)

*I am?* means you are surprised that you are the one that has been *promoted* (you were expecting something else to happen to you other than be promoted - or were not expecting a promotion to occur)

Comment: I would suggest you include JR's first comment.  "I was?" or "Was I" is more fitting than "I am?"

Answer (score 0):

If you say "me?" then it implies you know that someone should get promoted and you are surprised to know that the person is you.

If you say "I am?" (I think "Am I?" would also be correct) then it implies that you know something is going to happen with you and you are amazed to know that thing is a promotion.

Comment: I would suggest you include JR's first comment.  "I was?" or "Was I" is more fitting than "I am?"